# There are a lot of null value at Oracle Case

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table. I would like to create a view. I wrote a query what substitute the second table of the value with the correct name.

```
S_ID   | STATION_NAME
------ | ------
1      | PACKAGER1
2      | PACKAGER2
3      | PACKAGER3
4      | PACKAGER4
5      | PACKAGER5
6      | PACKAGER6
7      | PACKAGER7

C_ID   | STATION_ID | TO_STATION_ID
------ | -----------| -------------
1      | 1          | 7
2      | 2          | 7
3      | 3          | 7
4      | 4          | 7
5      | 5          | 7
6      | 6          | 7
7      | 7          | 1
7      | 7          | 2
7      | 7          | 3
7      | 7          | 4
7      | 7          | 5
7      | 7          | 6

SELECT CC.STATION_ID AS NUM,
       CASE WHEN CC.STATION_ID = S.S_ID THEN S.STATION_NAME END
         AS "FROM STATION"
FROM   CONNECTION CC,
       STATIONS S
```

The substituting work correctly, but creates a lot of other cell with null value. In all 12*7=82. How can I skip that case if the two value is not equal.

```
NUM    | FROM_STATION
------ | ------
1      | PACKAGER1
2      | null
3      | null
4      | null
5      | null
6      | null
7      | null
```

I would like to get this result:

```
NUM    | FROM_STATION | TO_STATION
------ | ------------ | ----------
1      | PACKAGER1    | Packager7
2      | PACKAGER2    | Packager7
3      | PACKAGER3    | Packager7
4      | PACKAGER4    | Packager7
5      | PACKAGER5    | Packager7
6      | PACKAGER6    | Packager7
7      | PACKAGER7    | Packager1
8      | PACKAGER7    | Packager2
9      | PACKAGER7    | Packager3
10     | PACKAGER7    | Packager4
11     | PACKAGER7    | Packager5
12     | PACKAGER7    | Packager6
```

Comment: hope you need what Gordon Linoff answered. Please refer this link, https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/joins.php  Hope this will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do and your query appear to have nothing to do with each other.  First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Second, I don't see what the `CASE` is for.  I suspect you want a query like this:

```
SELECT CC.STATION_ID AS NUM,
       S.STATION_NAME AS "FROM STATION"
FROM CONNECTION CC LEFT JOIN
     STATIONS S
     ON CC.STATION_ID = S.S_ID;
```

At the very least, this would appear to do something useful.

Comment: I modify the table and I wrote to the end my final expectaion